# Rails: How to override or make private a given scope from an included Concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope, activesupport-concern

I have a concern that adds a `scope` to `ActiveRecord` classes that include it. Most of the time its fine the way it is but depending on the class there might extra criteria that needs to be met. I don't want to have to rewrite the scope in the model but be able to just add on an extra criteria method.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # I've included the fact I pass a limit variable here because my scope also does this, in case that's relevant for solving this.
    # I'd like this to be private or not accessible via `MyModel._my_scope`
    scope :_my_scope, ->(limit = nil) { (joins, wheres, order etc etc).limit(limit) }
    scope :my_scope, ->(limit = nil) { _my_scope(limit) }
  end
end

class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  include MyConcern

  # Including the "private" scope to add my extra criteria.
  scope :my_scope, ->(limit = nil) { _my_scope(limit).where(foo: 'bar') }
end

class AnotherModel < ApplicationRecord
  include MyConcern

  # I like the default behavior here so nothing else to do
end
```

This works but from outside the class you can do this: `MyModel._my_scope` which I guess is ok - maybe theres a time when I'd want the default behavior - but in this case I dont think I do and I feel like encapsulating `_my_scope` is the way to go.

I'm assuming it's possible to make a private class method in `MyConcern` that gets included in `MyModel` but that doesn't seem to work and I'm not really a `Concern`/mixin master yet so not sure how to go about doing this. Also, are `Concerns` considered to be mixins? Is there a difference? That would be good to know also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same functionality of scopes with class methods, that you can inherit and extend for this case. It's not much different than your implementation; just avoids the use of the extra _ method by using a class method instead of a scope. E.g.

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def my_scope(limit = nil)
      (joins, wheres, order etc etc).limit(limit)
    end
  end
end

class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  include MyConcern

  def self.my_scope(limit = nil)
    super.where(foo: 'bar')
  end
end

class AnotherModel < ApplicationRecord
  include MyConcern
end
```

For the second part of your question: A concern is technically a ruby Mixin; it's just a convention to organize/group the Mixins that are included in your Models only as concerns. Using ActiveSupport::Concern allows you to add additional Model related functionality to your Mixins like scope, validations etc. which you can't get using a normal Module.
E.g. You can't do

```
module MyConcern
  scope :my_scope, ->(limit = nil) { _my_scope(limit) }
end

class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  include MyConcern # this will raise an error
end
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks.